Show who posted a question on the Active questions list
At present, the Stack Exchange software only shows who last interacted with a question in the active questions tab.
The last interactor is shown on the lower right of the question "tile":

Please consider adding who asked the question at the upper right of the question "tile":

A reason I think this should be changed:
As the question tab is now, it is too easy to attach the question in (at least my) mind to the last interactor, not the OP. By posting the OP's ID as well, it will be easier to see that this is the OP's question not Triplefault's or Ecnerwal's, etc.
(Yes, I should just simply remember that's how SE works, but it doesn't always happen. I look at the question and think, What did Ecnerwal ask today?)
From a comment by VLAZ I learn that the Questions page has Newest as a sort option, and shows the OP's info as the asker. However, SE sites' home page (XYZ.stackexchange.com not XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions) does not have Newest as a sort option, only Active, Hot, Week, and Month. I don't normally use the Questions page, only the Home page, since I don't like the partial start of the question text. It would be useful to have the OP show on the Active sort, as well as the last modifier.

Note about closure as duplicate: time is not relevant as long as it's the same request, and it wasn't done yet. This does not mean the request is invalid, and this is good to have it asked again in a bit different form as it both give new attention, and help with future search.

I just don’t think this is a priority. Seeing who wrote a question doesn’t really change how you interact with it, and if you really care, you can go to its page. Whether or not this would be good, there are so many other things that should be higher on the list.

Thanks for the thoughts! @ShadowWizard I did look through the suggested question search that pops up as I compose the question and did not see the duplicate. Off to vote there...

@ShadowWizard I actually do think that there is a slightly relevant difference in time:Since that request, it now says modified, which means the main thing the dupe said it wanted to fix is already done.

Why not go to the /questions page and sort by Newest? That shows only the askers. It doesn't show recently active, although if you were interested in that, you'd probably want to know who did the recent activity.

@VLAZ OK, I see what you're saying. The Questions page has Newest as a sort option, and shows the OP's info as the asker. SE sites' home page (XYZ.stackexchange.com not XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions) does not have Newest as a sort option, only Active Hot, Week, and Month. I don't normally use the Questions page, only the Home page, since I don't like the partial start of the question text. It would be useful to have the OP show on the Active sort, as well as the last modifier.

@Starship still not enough to mark the other one as completed.
